# Eclipse keyboard shortcuts: "alt+shift+" vs. "shift+" vs. "ctrl+alt+" etc. -- Is there an underlying logic?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

There are a zillion questions on SO about keyboard shortcuts in Eclipse, but there's I've always wondered if there is an underlying logic to the decisions of which shortcuts would be <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+[some letter], and which would be just <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+[some letter] etc. Obviously there is a need to use a variety of combinations because there are only so many keys on the keyboard, but why, for example, is "add import" <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>, while "extract method" is <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>, instead of the other way around?

I think if there is some underlying logic to these decisions, it will make it easier to remember more shortcuts without having to scan through the huge right-click menus to find them, and I won't accidentally use the wrong one as often.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have no definitive answer, but some elements could include:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>...</kbd>: those are mainly legacy shortcuts (for copy-paste for instance, or "new documents", or "save", ...).
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>...</kbd>: reserved for certain OS for **menu** shortcuts.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>...</kbd>: shortcuts for (mainly not always) *direct* actions (on the text or source code), like "add import")
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>...</kbd>:  shortcuts for (mainly, not always) *indirect* actions (a menu or windows is opened first, the user enter some other informations, and then the action is performed), like "extract method".
  Plus, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>...</kbd> is sometimes followed by a letter, like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (Show view), <kbd>B</kbd> (for showing breakpoints). Again: *indirect* action.